# Beginner to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am a beginner to Entity Framework.

I am learning using a tutorial.

The application consists in two fields and a submit button that are supposed to be added in a SQL SERVER EXPRESS database.

It seems that there is no interaction with the database at all. I do not know where to start because I have no error message since I corrected the one more below.

my model :

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int CustomerCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Z]{7,7}$")]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
}
```

my connection string in the web.config file :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add 
  name="CustomerDal" 
  connectionString="Data Source=localhost\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=MVC2db;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName=".NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server" 
  />
```

My Db context :

```
public class CustomerDal : DbContext 
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("tblCustomer");
    }

    public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }

}
```

the Submit action :

```
public ActionResult Submit(
// [ModelBinder(typeof(CustomerBinder))]
Customer obj) //validation runs 
{
 //   Customer obj = new Customer();

   // obj.CustomerCode = Request.Form["CustomerCode"];
  //  obj.CustomerName = Request.Form["CustomerName"];
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          CustomerDal Dal = new CustomerDal();
          Dal.Customer.Add(obj);     //in memory
          Dal.SaveChanges();          //physical commit 

          return View("Customer", obj);
      }
      else
      { 
          return View("EnterCustomer", obj);
      }
}
```

EnterCustomer.cshtml, where obj comes from

'
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Customer", FormMethod.Post))
        {

```
        <i>Customer Name : </i> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerName)

    <br>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CustomerName)
    <br>

        <i>Customer Code : </i> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerCode)

            <br>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.CustomerCode)
            <br>
            <input id = "Submit1" type = "submit" value = "submit"/>

            }
```

'

I have got a first error message about a duplicate key during the SaveChanges. After some research I added this line in the global.asax file :
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges());

Since then I do not have any error message but nothing happen when I enter a new item.

Comment: What is 'obj' ?

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Comment: Since I have tried to change the type of CustomerCode to Int, the error changed. Even when I retried with String, the error now is : "The model backing the 'CustomerDal' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database"

Comment: I edited my message to show where obj comes from. In debug mode, the values obj.CustomerCode and obj.CustomerName have the correct values before the error message occurs.

Comment: I do not understand how this additional layer of data between C# and SQL works. 
I have removed the line 
   Database.SetInitializer<CustomerDal>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<CustomerDal>());
in global.asax

Comment: if I add this line in the global.asax :
Database.SetInitializer<CustomerDal>(null);
the error does not show up, but another one : 
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'tbl Customer' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Answer (score 1):

The key in your model is an integer and by default is 0. When you save to the database, only one row can have that key. You must go to the table design and set the `CustomerCode` column to be an Identity Column to make it auto increment when new records come in. With your existing code, Entity Framework will retrieve the newly created key and put it in your CustomerCode property so you can use it in other places in your code if you wish.

You mention that you added `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` when trying to solve the problem; I believe this is unnecessary and might have unwanted effects when you change your model in future.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new blank object of type `CustomerDal` and saving it.
You already have all the values in the binded object `obj`

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //CustomerDal Dal = new CustomerDal();//REMOVE THIS LINE
        Dal.Customer.Add(obj);     //in memory
        Dal.SaveChanges();          //physical commit 

        return View("Customer", obj);
    }
    else
    { 
        return View("EnterCustomer", obj);
    }
```

Comment: `CustomerDal` is the OP `DbContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Popably in

```
public ActionResult Submit(
// [ModelBinder(typeof(CustomerBinder))]
Customer obj) //validation runs
```

you get empty object or null. So you add nothing to dbContext so nothing to save.

Debug app and check value in `obj` parameter.

Comment: obj parameter has correct values before the error occurs at SaveChanges